# Using Powershell to match a pattern on all occurrences in a text file

Tags: regex, powershell, match

I have a text file and I am using Powershell to list out the names present in the below pattern

Contents of the file:

```
beta-clickstream-class="owner:&quot;mike&quot;"
beta-clickstream-class="owner:&quot;kelly&quot;"
beta-clickstream-class="owner:&quot;sam&quot;"
beta-clickstream-class="owner:&quot;joe&quot;"
beta-clickstream-class="owner:&quot;john&quot;"
beta-clickstream-class="owner:&quot;tam&quot;"
```

Output I am looking for

```
mike
kelly
sam
joe
john
tam
```

Script I am using is

```
$importPath = "test.txt"
$pattern = 'beta-clickstream-class="owner:&quot;(.*?)&quot;"'
$string = Get-Content $importPath
$result = [regex]::match($string, $pattern).Groups[1].Value
$result
```

Above script is only listing the first name on the file. Can you please guide me on how to list all the names on the file.

Comment: Just use `-replace` --> `$string -replace $pattern,'$1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Get-Content` returns an *array* of strings, so you would have to call `[regex]::match()` on *each element* of array `$string`.

However, the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375), as suggested by [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings), enables a simpler solution:

```
(Get-Content $importPath) -replace '.+owner:&quot;([^&]+).+', '$1'
```

Alternatively, you could have read the file into a *single*, multi-line string with `Get-Content -Raw`, followed by [`[regex]::Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches) (multiple matches), not [`[regex]::Match()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match) (single match).